# Getting EventArgs from .NET event in LabVIEW

Tags: c#, .net, events, labview

[This example](http://www.ni.com/example/31047/en/) shows a `Labview vi` listening for a Click event from a `.NET` user control. The Click event has an *empty* `EventArgs`. If you change the event listened for to `MouseClick`, the `MouseEventArgs` is returned with the event. How do you extract the `MouseEventArgs` from the event in `Labview` and process the properties of the `MouseEventArgs`?

Here are the block diagrams from the cited example with the event changed to `MouseClick`:

[image]
[image]

**Woking solution provided by Yair:**
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you register an event callback, the VI is called each time the event happens and the event data is passed to the VI. Specifically, the **Event Data** cluster includes the event arguments object and that needs to be the correct class if you want to see the event data.

You can change this manually if you know which class it's supposed to be, or you can disconnect the static VI reference from the registration node and then right click the node and select **Create Callback VI**, which will create a new VI with the correct event class in the cluster, which you can now unbundle to access the event data. Now, the VI will run each time an event occurs and you can handle it.

Comment: I deleted the callback vi, and right-clicked |Create Callback, as Yair suggested, I unbundled the Event Data, and attached Property Nodes to the event arguments, and attached indicators to the Property Nodes. For some reason, the indicators only display when single-stepping, but my main question is answered. I will attach the block diagram that shows this.